# extra column condition in MySQL case statement not working

Tags: mysql

I have a condition where a field in MySQL can have the same value (a port number), but can represent two different devices, based on a host ID.  I've got the following, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
SELECT s.name AS 'ingester',
    d.dev_used AS 'size',
    Cast(CASE d.namespace_port
        (WHEN 4015 AND d.das_station IN(11,22,23)) THEN 'BPN1'
        (WHEN 4015 AND d.das_station NOT IN(11,22,23)) THEN 'SJC12'
        WHEN 4016 THEN 'SJC17'
        WHEN 4017 THEN 'SJC18'
        WHEN 4018 THEN 'SJC19'
        WHEN 4019 THEN 'SJC5'
        WHEN 4020 THEN 'SJC6'
        WHEN 4021 THEN 'SJC7'
        WHEN 4022 THEN 'SJC8'
        WHEN 4023 THEN 'SJC9'
        WHEN 4024 THEN 'SJC10'
        WHEN 4025 THEN 'SJC11'
        WHEN 4026 THEN 'SJC20'
        WHEN 4027 THEN 'SJC13'
        WHEN 4028 THEN 'SJC14'
        WHEN 4029 THEN 'SJC15'
        WHEN 4030 THEN 'SJC16'
    END AS CHAR) AS namespace,
    Date_format(d.date_attached, '%b-%e-%Y %l:%i %p') AS 'date_attached',
    Date_format(d.replication_started, '%b-%e-%Y %l:%i %p') AS 'date_started',
    Date_format(d.replication_completed, '%b-%e-%Y %l:%i %p') AS 'date_finished',
    Date_format(d.date_detached, '%b-%e-%Y %l:%i %p') AS 'date_detached'
FROM   das.stations s,
       das.device d
WHERE  d.das_station = s.id
AND svcid = "trrq"
ORDER  BY d.date_attached DESC
```

reading [MYSQL CASE STATEMENT MULTIPLE CONDITIONS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37460225/mysql-case-statement-multiple-conditions), it seems this should be possible, but when I try and execute the query, I get the following:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '4015 AND d.das_station IN(11,22,23)) THEN 'BPN1'
 4015 AND d.das_station NOT IN (1' at line 4
```

Is it not possible to have an AND condition within a case statement like this?

Edit:  it seems pasting into Mysql doesn't like the query

```
mysql> SELECT s.name AS 'ingester',
    ->     d.dev_used AS 'size',
    ->     Cast(CASE d.namespace_port
    ->
Display all 891 possibilities? (y or n)
    ->  (4015 AND d.das_station IN (11,22,23)) THEN 'BPN1'
    ->
Display all 891 possibilities? (y or n)
    ->  (4015 AND d.das_station NOT IN (11,22,23)) THEN 'SJC12'
    ->         WHEN 4016 THEN 'SJC17'
    ->         WHEN 4017 THEN 'SJC18'
    ->         WHEN 4018 THEN 'SJC19'
    ->         WHEN 4019 THEN 'SJC5'
    ->         WHEN 4020 THEN 'SJC6'
    ->         WHEN 4021 THEN 'SJC7'
    ->         WHEN 4022 THEN 'SJC8'
    ->         WHEN 4023 THEN 'SJC9'
    ->         WHEN 4024 THEN 'SJC10'
    ->         WHEN 4025 THEN 'SJC11'
    ->         WHEN 4026 THEN 'SJC20'
    ->         WHEN 4027 THEN 'SJC13'
    ->         WHEN 4028 THEN 'SJC14'
    ->         WHEN 4029 THEN 'SJC15'
    ->         WHEN 4030 THEN 'SJC16'
    ->     END AS CHAR) AS namespace,
    ->     Date_format(d.date_attached, '%b-%e-%Y %l:%i %p') AS 'date_attached',
    ->     Date_format(d.replication_started, '%b-%e-%Y %l:%i %p') AS 'date_started',
    ->     Date_format(d.replication_completed, '%b-%e-%Y %l:%i %p') AS 'date_finished',
    ->     Date_format(d.date_detached, '%b-%e-%Y %l:%i %p') AS 'date_detached'
    -> FROM   das.stations s,
    ->        das.device d
    -> WHERE  d.das_station = s.id
    -> AND svcid = "trrq"
    -> ORDER  BY d.date_attached DESC
```

if I remove the line wraps, it seems to paste correctly, however still isn't respecting the second field:

```
mysql> SELECT s.name AS 'ingester',    d.das_station,  d.dev_used AS 'size',     Cast(CASE d.namespace_port WHEN (4015 AND d.das_station = 11) THEN 'BPN1' WHEN (4015 AND d.das_station NOT IN(11,22,23)) THEN 'SJC12' WHEN 4016 THEN 'SJC17' WHEN 4017 THEN 'SJC18' WHEN 4018 THEN 'SJC19' WHEN 4019 THEN 'SJC5' WHEN 4020 THEN 'SJC6'  WHEN 4021 THEN 'SJC7' WHEN 4022 THEN 'SJC8'  WHEN 4023 THEN 'SJC9' WHEN 4024 THEN 'SJC10' WHEN 4025 THEN 'SJC11' WHEN 4026 THEN 'SJC20' WHEN 4027 THEN 'SJC13' WHEN 4028 THEN 'SJC14' WHEN 4029 THEN 'SJC15' WHEN 4030 THEN 'SJC16' END AS CHAR) AS namespace,     Date_format(d.date_attached, '%b-%e-%Y %l:%i %p') AS 'date_attached',     Date_format(d.replication_started, '%b-%e-%Y %l:%i %p') AS 'date_started',     Date_format(d.replication_completed, '%b-%e-%Y %l:%i %p') AS 'date_finished',     Date_format(d.date_detached, '%b-%e-%Y %l:%i %p') AS 'date_detached' FROM   das.stations s,        das.device d WHERE  d.das_station = s.id AND svcid = "trrq" ORDER  BY d.date_attached DESC;
+---------------+-------------+------+-----------+---------------------+--------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| ingester      | das_station | size | namespace | date_attached       | date_started | date_finished       | date_detached       |
+---------------+-------------+------+-----------+---------------------+--------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| ca-adsdas2-p1 |          11 | NULL | NULL      | Jan-20-2016 1:42 PM | NULL         | NULL                | Jan-21-2016 3:16 PM |
| ca-adsdas2-p1 |          11 | NULL | NULL      | Dec-21-2015 7:25 PM | NULL         | Dec-26-2015 9:22 PM | Jan-20-2016 1:33 PM |
+---------------+-------------+------+-----------+---------------------+--------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

if das_station = 11, it should say "BPN1" in namespace, not null.

Answer (score 0):

solved by including the namespace_port in the WHENs, as such:

```
SELECT s.name AS 'ingester',
    d.dev_used AS 'size',
    Cast(CASE WHEN (d.namespace_port = 4015 AND d.das_station IN (11,22,23)) THEN 'BPN1' WHEN (d.namespace_port = 4015 AND d.das_station NOT IN (11,22,23)) THEN 'SJC12' WHEN d.namespace_port = 4016 THEN 'SJC17' WHEN d.namespace_port = 4017 THEN 'SJC18' WHEN d.namespace_port = 4018 THEN 'SJC19' WHEN d.namespace_port = 4019 THEN 'SJC5' WHEN d.namespace_port = 4020 THEN 'SJC6'  WHEN d.namespace_port = 4021 THEN 'SJC7' WHEN d.namespace_port = 4022 THEN 'SJC8'  WHEN d.namespace_port = 4023 THEN 'SJC9' WHEN d.namespace_port = 4024 THEN 'SJC10' WHEN d.namespace_port = 4025 THEN 'SJC11' WHEN d.namespace_port = 4026 THEN 'SJC20' WHEN d.namespace_port = 4027 THEN 'SJC13' WHEN d.namespace_port = 4028 THEN 'SJC14' WHEN d.namespace_port = 4029 THEN 'SJC15' WHEN d.namespace_port = 4030 THEN 'SJC16' END AS CHAR) AS namespace,
    Date_format(d.date_attached, '%b-%e-%Y %l:%i %p') AS 'date_attached',
    Date_format(d.replication_started, '%b-%e-%Y %l:%i %p') AS 'date_started',
    Date_format(d.replication_completed, '%b-%e-%Y %l:%i %p') AS 'date_finished',
    Date_format(d.date_detached, '%b-%e-%Y %l:%i %p') AS 'date_detached'
FROM   das.stations s,
       das.device d
WHERE  d.das_station = s.id
AND svcid = "96wa"
ORDER  BY d.date_attached DESC
```

results in the following:

```
+------------------+--------------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+----------------------+---------------------+
| ingester         | size         | namespace | date_attached       | date_started        | date_finished        | date_detached       |
+------------------+--------------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+----------------------+---------------------+
| bpn-dasingest-p2 |         NULL | NULL      | Mar-29-2017 7:41 AM | NULL                | NULL                 | Mar-30-2017 8:58 AM |
| bpn-dasingest-p2 | 247547875328 | BPN1      | Mar-27-2017 7:55 AM | Mar-27-2017 9:33 AM | Mar-27-2017 12:27 PM | Mar-29-2017 7:41 AM |
+------------------+--------------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+----------------------+---------------------+
```

Comment: You are overlooking the significant change you made, in order to fix this.  You've completely switched between the [two styles of `CASE` expressiobs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html).  You switched from `CASE value WHEN [compare_value] THEN result ...` to `CASE WHEN [condition] THEN result ...`.  In your original, `WHEN` is followed by a *value for comparison*.  `(4015 AND d.das_station NOT IN (11,22,23))` is a logical expression that can only equate to 1 or 0, which won't ever match the value of namespace_port in any meaningful way.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot thanks for the comment.   That's actually how I caught it...after reviewing the first link I posted, I noticed I was trying to include the second field in the whole statement, instead of how the previous post included both conditions in each WHEN statement, rather than in the CASE statement.   My second issue was that for some reason while PHP can read the whole file in with spaces, copy+paste is not as forgiving into MySQL client, and was stripping my "WHEN"'s